# Source for the act of completing Shas if every daf is distributed and completed individually by a group of people?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

There is an unsourced claim I am seeking to verify. There is a claim that, if every daf of a masechet (and, by extension, Shas) is learned by a group of people - through the means of every person being assigned a daf (or as many are needed for the entire volume to be finished in aggregate), it is equivalent to each person in that group who learned their assigned daf finishing that particular masechet (and, by extension, Shas, if all masechtot have been learned). I am unable to find a source for this claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source is the Sdei Chemed Mareches mem:198 on communal syium hashas.

Text:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I’m not fluent in the text but does the Sdei Chemes davka mean each person must finish a Masechet ? His text reads - ״ומחלקים הש״ס בין כמה בני אדם שכל אחד לוקח מסכתא אחת״  . If this is the case, then perhaps just for splitting the masechtot there is a source, but not a further division of dafs.

Comment: He does write mashecet,but the idea is that you are finishing as one unit so you are all like one. I think a daf would fit in same category.